# Django: "extends" not working in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I followed the latest Django documentation, using the `{% extends %}` keyword the same way they do in their example but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

**base.html:** the `content` block defined in `transaction_detail.html` below works:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          {% if messages %}
          {% endif %}
          {% block content %}{% endblock %} <!--This block defined in transaction_detail.html is displaying correctly -->
        </div>
...
```

**transaction_detail.html:** Note that the `test` block is contained within the `content` block. Is that allowed?

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %} <!-- This block displays correctly -->

 <div class="content-section">
            <!-- Chat -->
            {% block test %} <!-- This block does not display at all -->
            
            {% endblock %}
<div>
...
```

**room.html:**

```
{% extends 'blog/transaction_detail.html' %}

    {% block test %}
        <div class="messages">
            <ul id="chat-log">
            </ul>
            <div class="message-input">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <input id="chat-message-input" type="text" placeholder="Write your message..." />
                    <button id="chat-message-submit" class="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

**settings.py (TEMPLATES variable only):** I have all apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        #DIRS: a list of directories where the engine should look for template source files, in search order.
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ''), # root directory
                 'django_project/blog/templates'], # templates in blog app
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I think I'm following the same parent/child relationship as base.html/transaction_detail.html in the transaction_detail.html/room.html parent/child relationship.

Comment: Exactly *what* is not working?

Comment: When I go to a view which loads `transaction_detail.html`, the `test` block I defined in room.html does not display.

Comment: @Tom If your view renders `transaction_detail.html` then why do you expect `room.html` to be rendered? `room.html` is extending `transaction_detail.html` not the other way round.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I thought since I extend transaction_detail.html in room.html, then room.html becomes a "child" of transaction_detail.html, and is therefore available to be used in transaction_detail.html

Comment: @Tom: no, the idea is that if you extend it, it means that if you *render* `room`, it will load the hierarchy, but if you do not render `room`, then `room` does not play any role at all, it is not loaded, not evaluated, etc.

Comment: @Tom Let me put it this way I can have multiple templates extend `base.html` now if I render `base.html` would all of these other templates be loaded? (Not to mention it would be difficult to find all the templates that extend this one)

Comment: Oh I think I get it. So the user must visit the child page, not the parent page. That's why when I visit transaction_detail, I can see the base.html content (because transaction_detail is the child). But room is the child of transaction_detail, so when i visit transaction_detail.html, that is why i don't see the room.html block. Is that correct?